# How to save a csv string file in python

Tags: python, string

I am new with python.

I have a loop with lime function which generate an output at each iteration :

```
file = []
res = output.as_list() at i=0 It contains [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1625), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.109)]
file.append(res)
res = output.as_list() at i=1 It contains [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1658), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.1118)]
file.append(res)
res = output.as_list() at i=2 It contains [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.15975), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.111309)]
file.append(res)
```

The final file contains:

```
[[('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1625), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.109)], [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1658), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.1118)], [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.15975), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.111309)]]
```

I want to save it in an csv file with 2 columns and 3 rows :

```
[('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1625), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.109)]
[('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1658), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.1118)]
[('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.15975), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.111309)]
```

I tried this but I am getting all value in one row

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    wr.writerow(file)
```

Comment: NameError:  `file` - [mre] please

Comment: How exactly did you create `file`? It would probably be easier to fix the problem there, by creating a (three-element) ist of (two-element) lists, rather than a single 6-element list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas, we can do this as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(input_list)
df.to_csv(output_path, index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably much more elegant ways, but a simple way of doing this is like the following:

```
mytuples = [[('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1625), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.109)], [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.1658), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.1118)], [('ft-1822 > 0.45', -0.15975), ('ft-1818 > 0.18', -0.111309)]]
with open('test.csv','w') as f:
    for mytuple in mytuples:
        f.write(str(mytuple)+ '\n')
```

You loop over the list and convert your list element into a string adding a Newline and then writing that list element to the file.